# usage of "versed"

Tags: word-usage

I came across the word "versed" and it seemed very useful to me. But the examples in dictionaries are very scanty, they are all, for some reason, restricted to the constructions like the sentence "*someone is versed in something*" or the noun phrase "*someone (who is) versed in something*". To better understand how to apply this word, I tried to come up with my own sentence:

X + *how many times a day to brush teeth, just google "brush teeth"*.

**(1)** X = *to be versed*
**(2)** X = *to be versed in*
**(3)** X = *to get versed*
**(4)** X = *to get versed in*

I know I can use "*to understand*" or "*to find out*" but I'm interested only in the variants having the word "*versed*".
So could you tell me please which of them are correct and which are not and why?

Comment: What do "X +" and "X =" mean? Are examples 1-4 supposed to come at the beginning of the sentence "_________ how many times..."?

Comment: To be versed in something is correct. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your suggestions are correct. Here is [the Collins Dictionary's definition of "versed"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/versed):

> If you are versed in or well versed in something, you know a lot about it.

One normally doesn't learn a lot about something by "just googling" it. Furthermore, the answer to "how many times a day to brush teeth" is presumably just a number, and I'm not sure how one could "know a lot about" such a number.

Here is a sentence that would work better:

> After much googling, I became well versed in the issue of how frequently a person should brush his or her teeth.

Comment: +1 Yes, it's having *a depth of knowledge* in something, acquired through *time spent studying or experiencing* it.